# How to use a pgfkey as multiple keys later on (in a tikzpicture environment for example)

Tags: pgfkeys

I usually define new latex commands to automate my draws using `pgfkey` to have a nice key-value syntax. For instance:

```
\MyCircle[radius=0.2cm]
```

Later on, I often find the need to extend those commands. For instance, I might want to have an overlay picture using the following options:

```
remember picture, overlay, shift={(-1,-0.3)}
```

Hence, to add some flexibility, I was thinking of adding an optional `tikzoptions` key:

```
\MyCircle[radius=0.2cm,%
          tikzoptions={ remember picture, overlay, shift={(-1,-0.3)} },%
         ]
```

Turns out it is not as easy as I thought, and the following attempt doesn't work:

```
\documentclass[varwidth,margin=0.5cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\MyCircle}[1][]{{%
  \pgfkeys{/MyCircle/.cd,%
    radius/.store in=\radius,%
    radius=1,%
    tikzoptions/.store in=\tikzoptions,%
    tikzoptions=,%
  }%
  \pgfkeys{/MyCircle/.cd, #1}%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[\tikzoptions]
    \draw (0,0) circle (\radius);
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}}

\begin{document}

-- Normal picture 
\MyCircle[radius=0.2cm]

-- Overlay picture 
\MyCircle[radius=0.2cm,%
          tikzoptions={ remember picture, overlay, shift={(-1,-0.3)} }]

\end{document}
```

Here is the expected output:

[image: Expected output]

How could I use the content of `\tikzoptions` as multiple key parameters for the `tikzpicture` environment? Is there a better way to achieve what I want to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use a `.style` handler:

```
\documentclass[varwidth,margin=0.5cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\MyCircle}[1][]{{%
    \pgfkeys{/MyCircle/.cd,
      radius/.store in=\radius,
      radius=1,
      tikzoptions/.style={tikzstyle/.style={##1}},
      tikzoptions={},
    }%
    \pgfkeys{/MyCircle/.cd,#1}%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[/MyCircle/tikzstyle]
      \draw (0,0) circle (\radius);
    \end{tikzpicture}%
  }}

\begin{document}

-- Normal picture 
\MyCircle[radius=0.2cm]

-- Overlay picture 
\MyCircle[radius=0.2cm,%
tikzoptions={ remember picture, overlay, shift={(-1,-0.3)} }]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Works great, thanks! I've seen many similar questions to mine and people where trying to use a `.style` handler but I couldn't figure out how to make it work.

The documentation is quite scarce about it. Should I be looking somewhere else than is subsection _82.4.4 Defining Styles_? Could you explain to me the `##1` syntax?

Comment: @remjg A simple `.style` handler is like a macro with one argument and its argument is `#1`. If you define a macro (or, here, a `.style`) within another macro definition (here `\MyCircle`), you must use `##1`.